# C# resolving generic type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, type-resolution

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way possible to resolve an interface's generic parameter type's inner generic type (i.e. `IList<T>` the type of `T`) while retaining the original concrete class. For example this is what I have now which works but doesn't read well when used.

```
public interface IFuzzyValue<TValueType>
{
    double Probability { get; }
    TValueType Value { get; }
}

public static class Util
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<TFuzzyType> ValueEquality<TFuzzyType, TValueType>() 
        where TFuzzyType : IFuzzyValue<TValueType>
    {
        return new ValueEqualityComparer<TFuzzyType, TValueType>();
    }
}
```

Now to create a value equality comparer for a concrete `IFuzzyValue` class I need to do the following.

```
class FuzzyString : IFuzzyValue<string>
{
    double Probability { get; }
    string Value { get; }
    ... other properties/methods
}

IEqualityComparer<FuzzyString> comparer = Util.ValueEquality<FuzzyString, string>();
```

The part I'm trying to address is to avoid having to supply both types to the `ValueEquality<FuzzyString, string>` method and instead infer the type `string` from the `FuzzyString` class itself.

```
IEqualityComparer<FuzzyString> comparer = Util.ValueEquality<FuzzyString>();
```

Is there any way this is possible in C#? I can't seem to find anyway around this type system limitation.

Comment: This is called partial inference, and its not supported. Generic inference is an all or nothing affair

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks for defining the name of the functionality I am looking for and for allowing me to give up hope for now ;)

Comment: There are some hacks and workarounds, though in this instance the class you are creating expects those 2 types, there is not really much you can do